# SQLAlchema, Python I want to filter my model by created date from day start to end of the day

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a model which I want to filter data by users input DateTime which will be from starting of day to end of the day, example DateTime from DateTime "2018-10-18T00:59:59.711602" to DateTime "2018-10-18T23:59:59.711602"

```
   @classmethod
   def filter_by_created_date(cls, query, **kwargs):
        getDate = kwargs.get("filter_by_created_date")
        getSecondArgsDate = kwargs.get("filter_by_created_date_second_args")

        if  getDate and getSecondArgsDate is not None:
            DBMediaItem = GrapheneType.db_cls("MediaItem")

            query = query.filter(
                DBMediaItem.created_at < getDate,
                DBMediaItem.created_at >= getSecondArgsDate
            )

        return query
```

Answer (score 1):

With between:

```
query = query.filter(DBMediaItem.created_at.between(getDate, getSecondArgsDate))
```

Comment: is the first argument "getDate"  the started from and second argument "getSecondArgsDate" date end to?